# Batch file to delete all files in directory except for system files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rmdir

I'm trying to write a batch file, that would delete all files and directories in DELETE directory, except for a few "important" ones. I've tried to add attributes Hidden and System to the important files/directories. While it seems to work on the "del" command, "rmdir" still removes everything, regardless of attributes.

```
@echo on

attrib  important.txt +s +h
attrib  folder +s +h
attrib  picture.bmp +s +h
attrib  delete.bat +s +h


del *.* 
rmdir /s /q C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\DELETE

attrib  important.txt -s -h
attrib  folder -s -h
attrib  picture.bmp -s -h
attrib  delete.bat -s -h

pause
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the attribute ***`r`*** (read-only)?

Comment: I've  tried it now, but it still removes everything

Comment: Please change the name of your `.bat` file, giving it the name of an internal command, `delete` is potentially very problematic. Also, I'm a little perplexed at why you think that changing file attributes just for this purpose is worthwhile. Unless you've got a huge directory tree, why not just recurse the tree listing deleting all except for the known file names. You can do that using `IF` or probably better `FINDSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in PowerShell. This can be placed into a .ps1 script file and run from the cmd.exe command shell.

Set the read-only attribute on the files to not delete.

```
(Get-Item .\important.txt).Attributes+="ReadOnly"
```

Use the following command to delete the files. When you are confident that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the end of the command.

```
Remove-Item -Path * -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
```